# can't see my virtual host entries in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, ufw

I'm experimenting with a bash program I built who creates virtual hosts in apache and sets all relevant system files like `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/apache2/hosts-available/*.conf`, create user's `home`, `php.ini` etc.

So far everything runs well and I can see my suexec users when typing `test1/index.php` or `test2/index.php` etc.

I decided to move onto vbox (**ubuntu server**) and run the script which completed successfully.
I managed to find the apache start page at http://192.168.56.1:2222/ (**now I doubt if that was from my guest** or from my host apache! Either way I edited the message in both machines so I know where I am!) as I set up guest's Network properties like this:

[image: vbox network 1]
[image: vbox network 2]

Immediately I noticed that I **couldn't** see my virtual hosts unless I was editing a vhost file and made him default as `sudo apache2ctl -S` showed me (but then **ALL** users showed that one)!

A typival vhost file:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test
  ServerAlias test
  ServerAdmin test@test.com
  DocumentRoot /home/test/public_html/

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  SuexecUserGroup test test
  <Directory /home/test/public_html/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/suexec/test/cgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper .php
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>

  LogLevel debug
  ErrorLog /home/test/log/apache_error.log
  CustomLog /home/test/log/apache_access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

My first thought was about guest's ufw so I decided to start playing with it. To make a long story short, now I **can't** see even apache's default page by typing in my host: `http://192.168.56.1:2222/`
even if I try `sudo ufw disable` or `sudo ufw reset` or `sudo ufw allow from 10.0.2.15` (at the guest).
Please note that `http://192.168.56.1/` shows my host apache.

The web page shows:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
Protocol mismatch.
```

My host's `ifconfig`:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:5f:f9:f0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e4b:4e1d:c7a2:c4e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:102930 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:69360918 (69.3 MB)  TX bytes:21795276 (21.7 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e2e00000-e2e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:23108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2514772 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2514772 (2.5 MB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:11332 (11.3 KB)
```

My guest's `ifconfig`:

```
magellan@cent:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4b:16:87  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4b:1687/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3027 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:407687 (407.6 KB)  TX bytes:356072 (356.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:349 (349.0 B)  TX bytes:349 (349.0 B)
```

At the moment `ufw` at my guest shows these:

```
magellan@cent:~$ grep 'DEFAULT_' /etc/default/ufw
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="DROP"
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"

magellan@cent:~$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active
```

Any ideas as what I can do?

Comment: command `sudo iptables -L` shows a suspicious entry  `ACCEPT     all  --  test                 anywhere` that remains from previous changes. Is this a symptom that `ufw` does a dirty job?

Answer (score 0):

I managed just to access apache default page in my guest by doing [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly):

1. I dropped all guest connections and created a new one host-only
   (File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks -> Create)
2. Then, at guest's Settings -> Network -> Adapter 1, Attached to: Host-only).

From guest's `ifconfig`

```
magellan@g3site001:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4b:16:87  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4b:1687/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6460 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:590863 (590.8 KB)  TX bytes:2738709 (2.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:349 (349.0 B)  TX bytes:349 (349.0 B)
```

I can access default page as `http://192.168.56.101/`
But still, I cannot access my hosts `http://192.168.56.101/suexec-test/index.php` or `http://192.168.56.101/test/index.php` etc. **???**

```
The requested URL /suexec-test/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Comment: I wrote a full tutorial there: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-set-up-networking-between-host-and-guest-in-vbox.74614/